# Shell Script to loop over files, aplly command and save each output to new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have read most questions regarding this topic, but can't get an answer to my specific question:

I have a number of files in a directory, and I want to apply a command to each of these files and then create a new file with the outpot for every single file. I can only manage to write it into one file alltogether. As i expect to have ~ 500.000 files, i also would need the script to be as efficient as possible.

```
for f in *.bed; do sort -k1,1 -k2,2n; done
```

This command sorts each file accordingly and writes the ouput in the Shell - But i cannot manage to write to file in the for-loop without appending it with ">>" .
I'm thankful for any answer providing an approach or an already answered question on this topic!

Comment: what is the input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use script like this:

```
for f in *.bed
do 
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n $f >>new_filename
done
```

If you want to be sure `new_filename` is empty before run the loop you can clear the content in file with command (before `for` loop):

```
>new_filename
```